# Instructive examples of elegant, clear, rigorous, terse, but "non-dull" mathematical prose

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, big-list, advice, article-writing

On the "About" page of the [Mathgen](http://thatsmathematics.com/blog/mathgen) project one can read:

> "More seriously, I think this project says something about the very
>   small and stylized subset of English used in mathematical writing.
>   This program only knows a handful of sentence templates, and yet I
>   think its writing style is not far off from many published papers. You
>   could argue this is bad (shows a lack of creativity) or good (makes
>   papers more accessible to those with a limited knowledge of English),
>   but I think we could stand to pay more attention to our writing
>   styles, instead of unthinkingly relying on stock phrases."

Starting from these considerations, I would like to ask a more general question on mathematical prose: could you point out some examples of "great" mathematical writing that you've came across over the years from which an undergraduate can learn how to write mathematics well (while understanding the content)?

I will define "great" as follows:

- showing masterful expertise;
- engaging, but rigourous and precise (as opposed to chatty and friendly but unclear and imprecise);
- elegant, terse (by which I mean polished, smoothly elegant, and to the point, but not brusque or abrupt or devoid of motivation), clear.

**Note (1):** I've read *A primer of mathematical writing*, which gives some sensible advice on writing in general, but I was looking for some actual examples of good mathematical prose.

**Note (2):** I guess that many of you will mention Rudin, so I would like to say that I'm already studing his book.

Comment: I think it's odd to list 'terse' as a positive attribute. The best written mathematical text I know is Spivak's "Calculus", which isn't terse. But elegant, rigorous, clear, and not dull: definitely.

Comment: @SimonS By "terse" I meant polished, smoothly elegant, and to the point, but not brusque or abrupt or devoid of motivation.

Comment: Ok then. A lot of mathematical writing is pretty awful. I'll be excited to see if others have good examples.

Comment: I like Feller's Introduction to Probability, especially, Vol. 1.

Comment: Knuth's writing fits these requirements, I think.

Comment: I would vote for Dijkstra's writings, see the archive of his works at http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I nominate Halmos.  All of his writing is good, but you might look in particular at
"Finite dimensional vector spaces".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, professor. I've indeed liked *Naive set theory* quite a lot. Could you tell me what kind of approach is followed in *Finite dimensional vector spaces*?

Comment: @Dal The kind of approach you'll see from a functional analyst. This isn't a book for beginners, it's more a neat presentation of the linear algebra that surrounds functional analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Pick up an issue of SIAM Review. I admit that I haven't read every article in every issue of late, but I cannot recall an article with less than "very good" writing, and most are excellent.

Answer (score 3):

There is a book by Bott and Tu called '[Differential forms in algebraic topology](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-90613-3)' which I think satisfies your criteria. In particular, you say it should be engaging and that is what I remember most about when I first read this book.